# Dynamically extend a layout in Jade

Tags: themes, pug

I have "theme" as information stored on my page object in MongoDB. Now, I retrieve the page, and in my router do a res.render("...", page). I would like to extend the right layout based on the theme in my jade file, as so:

```
- var theme = page.theme;
extends theme
```

This doesn't work though - I get an error! If I try the following

```
- var theme = page.theme
extends= theme
```

The page renders, but it doensnt pick up the theme.

**Question** Is there any way for me to extend a layout dynamically like this based on a variable? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any workaround is welcome!

Comment: @appa did you found any alternative ?

Comment: @AjayPatel have you tried https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/520#issuecomment-32777507 ?

Comment: @Ven Thanks, that is good alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; extends is compile-time and you can not use it render-time